# Using lists in MS Word Javascript API

Tags: javascript, typescript, ms-word

I need some help customizing [Word.Lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.list?view=word-js-preview) in MS Word via the JS API.

I'm implementing a Word add-in that manipulate both lists and styles inside the current document. What I want to do is create globa [Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.style?view=word-js-previewt) using the [Word.Document.addStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.document?view=word-js-preview#word-word-document-addstyle-member(1)) method and apply this custom Styles to paragraphs in a list. But when I do apply my Style to the paragraph it apparently stops belonging to the list. I think I'm missing some configuration in my Styles that are causing this behavior.

I've written the exemple code bellow to explain my intention and problem:

```js
async function insertList() {
  await Word.run(async (context) => {
    //Start by cleaning the document
    const body = context.document.body;
    body.clear();
    await context.sync();

    //Create custom style
    const styleName = "MyTestStyle";
    const style = context.document.addStyle(styleName, "Paragraph");
    style.set({
      paragraphFormat: {
        alignment: "Justified",
        lineUnitAfter: 0,
      },
      font: {
        size: 12,
        name: "Arial",
        bold: false,
        underline: "None",
      },
    });
    await context.sync();

    //Create a paragraph and start a list
    const list = body.insertParagraph("Start of the list", "Start").startNewList();
    list.load("$none");

    await context.sync();

    // To add new items to the list, use Start or End on the insertLocation parameter.
    list.insertParagraph("Second element", "End");
    const paragraph = list.insertParagraph("End of the list", "End");

    // paragraph.styleBuiltIn = Word.BuiltInStyleName.strong;
    paragraph.style = "MyTestStyle";

    // Set numbering for list level 1.
    list.setLevelNumbering(0, Word.ListNumbering.arabic);

    await context.sync();
  });
}
```

The result of running the code above is the following:
[image: Exemple result]

As you can see, the last element of my list, the one I have applied the style to, loses the Word.List formatting.

Any help in this topic will be much appreciated.